# Possible bug with New-AzureDeployment

Tags: azure, powershell-cmdlet, azure-deployment, azure-powershell

The **New-AzureDeployment** cmdlet is not updating the Deployment Name with the value from the -Name parameter. As per MSFT's documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj152867.aspx), the **-Name** parameter maps to the Deployment Name but when I tested, it was the Deployment Unique name that got updated with the value of **-Name** parameter. Moreover, I could use special characters like **'.'** and **'/'** in deployment name when uploading the package directly from portal,  but the cmdlet wouldn't let me use any special characters

Wondering if someone had run into this issue?

Here is the screenshot of the error that I am seeing when using special characters

> New-AzureDeployment : HTTP Status Code: BadRequest - HTTP Error
>   Message: The deployment name is invalid

[image]

Comment: What are you using for `-Name` and `-ServiceName` parameters currently?

Comment: Got some more information from testing... I will update the post shortly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `-Label` option to specify user friendly name (your custom desired name that will be shown in the portal).

`-Name` option is for system-use, and is assigned to a GUID if not specified.

Here is where in the portal these switches are represented:

[image: deployment details]

Comment: The names for the parameters should have been better picked but this helped me. Thank.